# Make "Account Dashboard" link to redirect to two different dashboards based on customer type

Tags: login, customer-group, dashboard

Now based on two different user groups named "Customers"(the default ones in magento) and "Members"(our customized ones), I have different info. to display and so two different dashboards for both type of users.

The functions related to "Members" is handled by our custom module of membership.

But at the same time, the group "Members" retain functionality of being both "Customers" as well as "Members". So when a Member login he can see the same left navigation as normal customers.

But the part is here "Account Dashboard" is a link that always redirects to a normal customer dashboard rather than the Member ones.

So i want that, when a normal customer logs-in, that should redirect to a normal dashboard but when a Member logs-in, it should redirect to a Member dashboard from each page!

How do I achieve this???? 
Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break this down into a few steps:

- Make a controller that handles the initial login (lets call it MembersLoginController)
- In the indexAction (lets assume this is where the customer is going) check what group the customer is from using the following code:

  `$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();`
- Using an if statement redirect the customer to the link you want using this code:

  `$this->_redirect($url);`
- **Important** Make sure that any action method you have declared in the controller checks whether the customer is logged in and has permission to see that page (you can create a helper method that returns tru/false)

Comment: actully, the member when logs-in, he can see his dashboard(the customized ones). But when he navigates to different pages like "account information","my orders", etc. , and if he clicks on "account dashboard", he sees the default ones of magento, instead of his dashboard. this is what creates problem.